# Best practice for where to put declarations?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Im kind of new to using type checkers in JavaScript and am just curious, currently I have my `.flowconfig` reading my global declarations from a declarations folder and some of my React components have the declarations in the component module, what is the best practice for which declarations go where?

Should they all be put in a declarations folder in one location or do you put them all in their relevant module, i.e. HeaderPropTypes gets declared in my Header Component, in which case then what is the declarations folder for if everything is declared at the module level?

Also, same question but for third party code I want to add declarations for, should they be in the component that uses them or in a declarations folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I talked to someone on the flow IRC channel about this and his ideas make sense to me, so I am posting those here for other people's benefits.

3rd party code (node_modules, bower_components, external scripts) can be placed in the declarations folder.

For my own code, put the type declaration in the component file or file that needs that type first.  If a few files need that type and there is no obvious owner, then you can create a types file in the parent folder for that part of the system.

Comment: This is also useful for those who don't know how to export and import types: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/